# What is difference between hint in TextInputLayout vs hint in TextInputEditText

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I found crash in crashlog of "NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.getBoundsOnScreen(android.graphics.Rect)' on a null object reference" and I verified some stackoverflow suggestions for this crash. I found below link suggest to use hint in TextInputLayout instead of TextInputEditText, so I want to know what makes it different?

Below link suggests to use hint in TextInputLayout:
[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44187210/1619595)
Google shows to use hint in TextInputEditText:
[Google_Recommendation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#setHint(java.lang.CharSequence))

I tried hint in both place of TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText. Hint worked well in both place similarly.

I would like to know what is the difference between both method and which one is more appropriate to use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In design support library `TextInputLayout` was introduced to display the floating label on `EditText` or `TextInputEditText` . The `EditText` or `TextInputEditText`  has to be wrapped by `TextInputLayout` in order to display the floating label.

**Rule of Thumb** : `TextInputLayout` should wrap `TextInputEditText`

**where should you place hint**

according to the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputEditText.html)

> The hint should be set on the **TextInputLayout**, rather than the **EditText**. If a hint is specified on the child **EditText** in XML, the **TextInputLayout** might still work correctly; **TextInputLayout** will use the **EditText's** hint as its floating label. However, future calls to modify the hint will not update **TextInputLayout's** hint. To avoid unintended behavior, call setHint(CharSequence) and getHint() on **TextInputLayout**, instead of on **EditText**.

**Note** that `TextInputEditText` is special sub-class of `EditText` designed for use as a child of `TextInputLayout`.

hope it's helpful

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
What if I have **TextInputEditText** inside **TextInputLayout**?

Comment: Its like you have EditText since textInputEdittext is subclasd of edit text so you apply the same rules on TextInputEdittext

Comment: I notice if im using the android studio layout editor to drop in a TextInputLayout element it is putting the hint in the nested TextInputEditText. Is the editor doing it wrong or is that the correct placement?